# How do you center div while keeping the contents inside the div in place

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a div while keeping its contents in place.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
  .wrap{
    position: relative;
  }

  .character{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10%;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
  }
</style>

<div class="wrap">
  <img class="background" src="https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/348/300/844/digital-digital-art-artwork-planet-fantasy-art-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
  <img class="character" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KWjPQjV1ZZXvMBFNjab-HK3ZHTO5zSpkPTFf3x-d87RNBMnZ3A2hCbTZNumHxfydGQ">
</div>
```

Here is the result I am getting[image]

And here is what I am trying to achieve.
[image]

Comment: I don't see any attempt to centre the div?

Comment: I tried text-align: center on wrap class but it didn't do anything

Comment: it isn't text :)

Comment: So how do you center it? That's my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to center an image using CSS: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp

```
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0)
}

.character {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="background" src="https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/348/300/844/digital-digital-art-artwork-planet-fantasy-art-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
  <img class="character" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KWjPQjV1ZZXvMBFNjab-HK3ZHTO5zSpkPTFf3x-d87RNBMnZ3A2hCbTZNumHxfydGQ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a solution to align div in center, well there are other ways to but not working well along with **responsiveness**. So here is the solution in which I add an *extra container* to contain **wrap** class, then align to center.

You can try next time

> ***Margin: 50px auto;***
>   This can also center the element inside body, but it's not working here.

```css
.container{
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
                  
.wrap{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.character{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -10%;
     left: 0;
     height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="wrap">
          <img class="background" src="https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/348/300/844/digital-digital-art-artwork-planet-fantasy-art-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
          <img class="character" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KWjPQjV1ZZXvMBFNjab-HK3ZHTO5zSpkPTFf3x-d87RNBMnZ3A2hCbTZNumHxfydGQ">
        </div>
      </div>
```